# SharePoint Library with misc InfoPath forms (edit in browser)

Tags: 2010, infopath, sharepoint-server

I have inherited a project and not 100% sure how it was configured to make it work.

There are 7 forms in this library. They're not templates for a document library that I'm aware, but when you use the web based "Filler", there are Submit and Close buttons at the top of the form (created by the original designer). The code for these forms basically takes 3 fields and migrates the data accordingly.

I have opened the forms from within the library using the desktop client and did the save button, works fine (stores correctly). However, I need to make it where web based editing works (I made sure to keep the checkbox ticked for this).

I go through the process of doing the upload form template and I'm getting some formatting messages:

```
1) Margins with auto which is the way it was initially.
2) header/footer, apparently can't be used in the browser version. Didn't add, 
   so shouldn't be a concern either.
3) (more concerning to me, though I do have upgrade form if it exists checked so maybe
   a non issue) One or more form templates with this file name already exist on 
   the server. You may encounter problems from activation if a form template with 
   the same file name is already present in the site collection.
```

However, verification status = success and form template is ready to upload to the server (asides from the previously mentioned formatting messages + the existing file name one).

After that, I go to the activate for site collection area, activate, and the forms are listed as ready.

I have no intention of this being used as a form for a library/list, the goal is for them to edit data in the browser, click the submit button that was added, and it filter the saved file to a folder in the site. Presumably the codebehind solution for this handles it (if I do Edit in Microsoft InfoPath, it works as expected).

edit: the thing I am most confused by is that after activation, the form template lists as "ready". When I go to the site's library that the form is uploaded to, same name as the form name listed in the form template one and it says that the code can't be used as it was deactivated?

The exact message given is: The custom code in the form cannot be run because the solution has been deactivated in the Solution Gallery.

I go into Site Collection -> Gallery -> Solutions and it appears to be a bunch of .wsp files. The odd part is that the ones listed are from 2 years ago (probably the last time it was updated). Should deploying the .xsn to Central Admin generate a .wsp file in the solution gallery? I'm assuming my issue is that the two are no longer linked (old version wsp vs new version xsn).

Comment: Is there a .wsp file with your form's name in it in the Solution Management List in Central Administration?

Comment: There is. But it was for the previous maintainer's push (2013).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you upload a file with code behind directly into Central Administration, there will be a .wsp File in the Solution Management List. I would recommend to you to remove the old Form and the old .wsp File there and upload it again then. 
And don't forget to publish the form in "Administrator approved"-mode before you upload it :)